# Calculate shadow map to overlay hidden line-of-sight things in 2d?

Tags: 2d, geometry, platformer

Given a 2D sideview with even-sized grid squares and our hero in a known center-ish position like this

[image]

... and imagining this hero's line of sight like this...

[image]

how could one get the point values needed for the black overlay polygons as shown here? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Though it doesn't directly answer the question, and the page describes 2D lighting, I think the following page me be of help (particularly the bottom part): http://greweb.me/2012/05/illuminated-js-2d-lights-and-shadows-rendering-engine-for-html5-applications/

Comment: Sweet, especially as we're using JS/ Canvas here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

you can do the simple scaling trick.

yea too lazy to explain, just look at the image and ask if you don't understand

In this example I just scaled by a factor of 2. Higher values give longer shadows.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, how do you determine the locations of the scaled blocks?

Comment: I just scaled with the eye position as the origin.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need raycasting or walltracking to solve this.

This [link](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/) might help you out.
It shows the basic idea behind raycasting and walltracking with some interactive examples.

edit 1: changed raytracing to raycasting on first line, comment pointed out my brainfart

edit 2: Only use raycasting on the corners of your square, the rest can be interpolated.
No need to cast endless amount of rays.

Comment: I think you mean raycasting. Raytracing is used for computer graphics to create [ultra realistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)) images, although it can take a very long time. I get what you mean though :)

Comment: no you don't need raycasting. And I wouldn't recommend raycasting since a lot of rays would be required.